# Generate PNG from from table in dita-file

Tags: xml, png, dita, generate

I have many .dita files containing tables like the one shown below. I am trying to generate png images from these tables, preferably using python, but I can not seem to find any information or packages to do so. Is there something I am missing?

```
<table colsep="1" id="tableRadio" rowsep="1">
  <title>Key to Radio Components</title>
  <tgroup cols="2">
    <colspec colname="col1" colnum="1" colwidth="0.46*"/>
    <colspec colname="col2" colnum="2" colwidth="1.36*"/>
    <thead>
      <row>
        <entry colname="col1" valign="top">
          <p>Position</p>
        </entry>
        <entry colname="col2">
          <p>Component</p>
        </entry>
      </row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <row>
        <entry colname="col1">
          <p>A</p>
        </entry>
        <entry colname="col2">
          <p>Support</p>
        </entry>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate some kind of graph based on a DITA table you can try to use XSLT to create an SVG image like this publishing plugin does: https://github.com/oxygenxml/dita-table-svg
Then convert SVG to PNG.
If you want some kind of screenshot of the html output obtained from the table possibly you can find an application which takes screenshots.